Closeness of the operator $(Tx )(n)= nx(n).$
Let $\mathcal{l}^1=\{x=(x(1), x(2), \cdots x(n),\cdots )\mid \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x(n)|<\infty\}$ be the sequence space equipped with the  norm $\|x\|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x(n)|$. Consider the subspace $$X=\{x\in\mathcal{l}^1\mid \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n|x(n)|<\infty \}$$ and the transformation $$T: X\to\mathcal{l}^1 $$ given by $$(Tx)(n)= n x(n), n= 1, 2, 3, \cdots n, \cdots .$$ Prove that $T$ is a closed operator.
I tried as follows
Let $$x^m(n)\to x(n)$$ and $$T(x^m(n))= nx^m(n)\to y(n). $$ Then $$\| x^m(n)- x(n)\|\to 0~\text{as} ~m\to\infty$$ and therefore $$\| nx^m(n)- nx(n)\|\to 0~(\text{ multiplying both sides by $n$}). $$
But the limit is unique, so we must have $$nx(n)=T(x(n))=y(n)$$ and hence $T$ is closed .
Please check my calculation and suggest me . Thank you.

You claim $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x^m(n)-x(n)\right|\to 0$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|nx^m(n)-nx(n)\right|\to 0$. I think this needs justification. Probably need to use $Tx^m \to y$ before the last line.

@Steen82 it’s not summation, it’s sequence with norm . If you can do more better please clear it . Thank you.

@AndréCaldas what is solve is wrong way ??

Sorry, I accidentally removed my comment. The inverse is clearly bounded, $|T^{-1}| \leq 1$ and it is therefore continuous. So, $T$ is closed. I don't know if your solution is wrong... I am focusing on the "please suggest me part". :-)

@AndréCaldas so you write as $|T^{-1} ((x(n))|= | \frac{1}{n} x(n)| \leq |x(n)|??$

Summation is the definition of the norm ?

@Steen82 Yes you are right .  The second reason is ok for boundedness of $T^{-1}$?

I would apply the definition: assume $|x^{(m)}- x|_1\to 0$  and $|Tx^{(m)}-y|_1\to 0.$ The norm convergence imply the pointwise convergence. Hence $|x^{(m)}(n)- x(n)|\to 0$ and $|nx^{(m)}(n)- y(n)|\to 0$ when $m\to\infty.$ Thus $|x^{(m)}(n)-y(n)/n|\to 0.$ Hence $x(n)=y(n)/n,$ which implies $x\in X$ and $Tx=y.$

@RyszardSzwarc Sir how you write the step $| x^m(n)-\frac{y(n)}{n}|\to 0?$

Because of point wise cgt ?

Because $|x^{(m)}-x|\to 0$ and $x(n)=y(n)/n.$

I think your arguments are problematic, because you seem to make some confusion with this "$n$" in $x(n)$ or $x^m(n)$.
Remember that when people talk, for example, about the function $f(x) = 5x$, the function is not $f(x)$. The name of the function is $f$.
Saying $x^m \rightarrow x$, has a very precise meaning. However, when you say $x^m(n) \rightarrow x(n)$, this gets ambiguous. I guess this ambiguity is what makes you think that
$$
\|x^m(n) - x(n)\| \rightarrow 0
\Rightarrow
\|nx^m(n) - nx(n)\| \rightarrow 0
$$
is an obvious conclusion. But actually there is no "multiplying both sides by $n$", because there is no "$n$" in $x(n)$. You are saying $x(n)$ instead of $x$. If you use $x$, your conclusion becomes:
$$
\|x^m - x\| \rightarrow 0
\Rightarrow
\|nx^m - nx\| \rightarrow 0,
$$
by multiplying both sides by $n$. Well... this is true for any $n$. If there was an $n$! But there is no fixed $n$ to multiply.

Caldas your comment about boundedness is also good .

Let $\ell^1$ denote the set of sequences $z=(z(1),z(2),z(3),\ldots)$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|z(k)|<\infty$ equipped with the norm $\|z\|:=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|z(k)|$.  Let $T$ be defined by $(Tz)(k):=kz(k)$, $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ on the domain $\mathrm{dom}(T):=\{z\in\ell^1:\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|kz(k)|<\infty\}$. Note $\mathrm{dom}(T)$ is the set of $z\in\ell^1$ for which $Tz$ is in $\ell^1.$
We will show $T$ is a closed operator, that is supposing $x^m\in \mathrm{dom}(T)$, $m=1,2,3,\ldots$, $x,y\in\ell^1$, $\|x^m- x\|\to 0$ as $m\to\infty$,  and $\|Tx^m - y\|\to 0$ as $m\to\infty$ we must show $x\in \mathrm{dom}(T)$ and $Tx=y.$
For any $n$, $|x^m(n)-x(n)| \leq  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x^m(k)-x(k)| =\|x^m - x\|$, hence $x^m(n)\to x(n)$ as $m\to\infty.$
Similarly, for any $n$, $|nx^m(n)-y(n)| \leq  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|kx^m(k)-y(k)| =\|Tx^m - y\|$  so $n x^m(n) \to y(n)$ as $m\to \infty$ and therefore $x^m(n)\to \frac{1}{n}y(n)$ as $m\to\infty.$
As $m\to\infty$ the sequence $x^m(n)$ converges to both $x(n)$ and  $\frac{1}{n}y(n).$  Hence, $x(n)=\frac{1}{n}y(n)$ for any $n$.
Since $y\in\ell^1$ it follows that $x\in\mathrm{dom}(T)$ and for any $n$, $(Tx)(n)=nx(n)=n\frac{1}{n}y(n)=y(n),$ so $Tx=y.$
